# Converting a old loop in a Java8 loop

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I am completely new in Java8, I have this piece of code

```
for (Menu menu : resto1.getMenu()) {
    MainIngredient mainIngredient = MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(menu.getName());
}
```

that I want to refactor to make it faster, and I would like to convert it in a

```
List<CompletableFuture<MainIngredient>>
```

I have tried

```
List<CompletableFuture<MainIngredient>> priceFutureList = resto1.getMenu().stream()
            map(menu -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(menu.getName()), executorService));
```

but I got this error:

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Menu> to 
     List<CompletableFuture<MainIngredient>>
```

Then I also tried this

```
CompletableFuture<List<MainIngredient>> mainIngredient =        
    CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() ->  resto1.getMenu()
                                .stream()
                                .map(menu -> MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(menu.getName()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()), executorService);
```

But I got a `CompletableFuture<List<MainIngredient>>` instead of `List<CompletableFuture<MainIngredient>>`

Comment: `resto1.getMenu().stream()
            map(menu -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(menu.getName()), executorService)).collect(toList());`

Comment: You just need to combine the two you have.  Add `.collect(Collectors.toList());` on the end of your first attempt.  You've generated the `Stream` that you want, you just haven't turned it into a `List` afterwards.

Comment: what returns `getMainIngredient() ...`? see this `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("test","this");
       List<CompletableFuture<String>> completableFutures =  list.stream().map(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->s+" Hi"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first solution, you are missing the `collect(toList())`:

```
List<CompletableFuture<MainIngredient>> priceFutureList = resto1.getMenu().stream()
            .map(menu -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> MainIngredient.getMainIngredient(menu.getName()), executorService))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```